# Response from railway site in android app

Tags: android, html

I want to create railway app which takes train number date and lot more things from user and i want to pass that number in railway site ( http://enquiry.indianrail.gov.in/ntes/ ) and want result in my app.

Answer (score 0):

To access Indian Railways data you firstly need access to their data. As per my search, they have released an API for it. [This post](http://trak.in/tags/business/2014/09/26/erail-indian-railways-api-access/) outlines how you can access the API. You can find the official API docs [here](http://api.erail.in/).

Visit these links and assess the API scope and your use cases. This should give you a good start.

Comment: thank u for reply. But sir to get api key from erail we need to first send mail requesting them for api key. I mailed them 2-3 times in last 1.5 mnth. But they haven't replied.

Comment: Well thats Indian Railway for you :). Anyway, study their API well and make a well informed request for API key to them so they take you seriously. Not as a student or an enthusiast but, as a serious app developer. Then, they may provide you the key. No need to call me sir.

Comment: is there any otger method??  I heard that on passing train number using my app on this link. http://enquiry.indianrail.gov.in/ntes/  . I can gethtml in response and on parsing that html i can get required info. Using Get or something.

Comment: Yeah, I stumbled upon that too but, I haven't tried or implemented that method myself.

Comment: ohh, no problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For doing this you have to work on API. For that first register on http://api.erail.in/ . On registering you will get API KEY which you have to use while calling API. Like this :-

```
http://api.erail.in/trains/?key=API_KEY&stnfrom=NDLS&stnto=BCT&date=5-sep-2014&class=3A
```

For getting details you have to call this api with passing details via URL (GET method).

Above API will give you trains between BCT and NDLS dated 5-sep-2014 in 3A class.

In return you will get `JSON Objects` and `JSON Arrays` which have to parsed.

Sample JSON

```
 {
    "status" : "OK",
    "result" : [
                    { 
                        "trainno" : "12138",
                        "name" : "PUNJAB MAIL",
                        "class" : "1A,2A,3A,SL,GN",
                        "rundays" : "M,Tu,W,Th,F,Sa,Su",
                        "from" : "NDLS",
                        "fromname" : "New Delhi",
                        "dep" : "05.15",
                        "to" : "CSTM",
                        "toname" : "Mumbai CST",
                        "arr" : "07.35",
                        "pantry" : "Yes",
                        "type" : "Super Fast",
                        "datefrom" : "05-SEP-2014",
                        "dateto" : "06-SEP-2014",
                        "traveltime" : "1620"
                    },
                    ....
                ]
}
```

To get routes of a train with train number call

```
http://api.erail.in/route/?key=API_KEY&trainno=12138
```

This will give response

```
    "status" : "OK",
    "result" : { 
                 "trainno" : "17603",
                 "name" : "Kcg Ypr Exp",
                 "route" :
                    [
                        {
                            "cls" : "1A 2A 3A SL",
                            "stn" : 
                                [
                                    {
                                        "code" : "KCG",
                                        "name" : "Kacheguda",
                                        "arr" : "First",
                                        "dep" : "21:00",
                                        "day" : 1,
                                        "remark" : ""
                                    },
                                    ....
                                ]
                         },
                          ...
                      ]
                  }
}
```

In short for calling any API you should have your own API KEY, which you will get after registering.

Using API you can performs many tasks like:-

- Get Station List
- Get Trains between stations
- Routes
- Fare
- Full Route
- Seat Availability
- Live train status
- cancelled trains
- diverted trains
- rescheduled trains
- and many more

Explore more on [this.](http://api.erail.in/)

Comment: Thanks for this nice and detailed explanation. I tried many times, for registr we need to mail them, i sent them 2-3 times but there is no  reply.